# as3 declaring an eventListener - variable scope

Tags: actionscript-3, scope, addeventlistener

**How do I declare an Event Listener to be public so it's available to all funcitons?**

```
// Coded needed below to declare Event

function addEventL()
   {
   /// Declares it in a function
   myMovie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuIn);
   }

function removeEventL()
   {
   /// This does not work because it was first called in a function.
   /// So it can not find the event Listener to remove.  
   myMovie.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuIn);
   }
```

Comment: what is the relationship between the three functions (addEventL, removeEventL, menuIn).   are they all in the same scope?

Comment: your code as shown (all in the same scope) would work.

Comment: Event listeners are not affected by scope. The only scope issue that could happen is if the handler is not within scope.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the function which nests the event listener into a public function:

```
package example
{ 
 public function addEventL()
 {
 /// Declares it in a function
 myMovie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuIn);
 }
}
```

Comment: This is very good. Unfortunately I am not using a class but hard coding in Flash Pro. It says public can only be used in packages.

Comment: Try adding the code into a package. I edited the answer for you.

Comment: Not sure that is going to work because I have to put all my code in a package then. I have like several lines in several key frames. What I want to  maximize my code. Only add event listeners when needed and delete them when not. Is this a waste of time? Do eventlistners hurt more or is adding the extra code hurting more?